# Trying to draw using information from array

Tags: javascript, svg

Trying to draw some circles from array and it draws only the last circle.
But when i try to `consle.log` the array it splits out all the coordinates.

JS

```
for (var i = 0; i < points.length; ++i) {

            circle.setAttribute('cx', points[i]["x"]);
            circle.setAttribute('cy', points[i]["y"]);
            circle.setAttribute('stroke', 'red');
            circle.setAttribute('stroke-width', 5);
            circle.setAttribute('r', 5);
            circle.setAttribute('fill', 'green');
            circle.setAttribute('fill-opacity',0);
            circle.setAttribute('id',points[i]["id"]);
            circle.addEventListener('contextmenu', function(event) {
              circle.remove(circle.id);
              event.preventDefault();
            });
            console.log(points[i]);
            customSvg.appendChild(circle);
           }
```

Comment: Make sure you're creating the `circle` element within the loop, otherwise you will just be replacing attributes on the original element each time.

Comment: Thank you, i just didnt see it. It was the problem.